# How to reorder div class on mobile?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can i reorder class on mobile? i want to put the title first, then the image, then paragraph and the button.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="pt-5">Title</h3>          
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">submit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 align-self-center">
            <img src="img/duo.png" alt="image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check the image below for more details

[image]

Comment: Which Bootstrap version?

Comment: @Zim it's seems a mix between the 3 and the 4 ...

Comment: Have you looked into using media queries?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with your current html layout and also I think you would need to use your own styles rather than bootstraps

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7   i can use bootstrap 4 too if their is a solution or custom css

Comment: Not a html or css fix, but a quick way would be to use some jquery, if you can. I've had to do stuff like this before and used `.insertAfter()`. http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstarp 4 then you can use order class to reorder your div

for eg:

```
<div class="order-sm-2 order-1"></div>
<div class="order-sm-1 order-2"></div>
```

You can do by CSS also. Make sure you are using FLEX properties

```
    .your_class{
         order: 2;
     }

    .your_class1{
        order: 1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with bootstrap, but for non bootstrap ideas, I could think of two potential solutions one could use here. First you could add the image under the title and hide it on desktop screens and then use `display: block` for mobile screens using media queries.

Second, I'm not sure if you can use jquery or not, but here is a potential jquery solution using .`insertAfter()`. Then once you detect a mobile size, you can place that image wherever you would like. Like such:

```
var isMobile = 768;

if ($(window).width() <= isMobile) {
    $('.duo').insertAfter('.pt-5'); 
}
```

You can test that here: http://jsfiddle.net/3buty5oL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
if($(window).width() < 767){//first check the device width
$(".image img").insertAfter(".pt-5");//move the image after title
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="pt-5">Title</h3>          
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">submit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 align-self-center image">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it can be done using juery in two steps
1. check for device width.
2. if its mobile then move the image next to title.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use `bootstrap4` order classes to recorder the elements on the screen. But based on the structure (i.e., on Desktop you kind of have 2 columns but on Mobile you have 1 vertical column where Image sits in between Title and Paragraph), it is not so easy to just use order classes to achieve the desired result.

I think the best way to achieve the result is to put the Image on 2 places and show/hide one of them based on the screen width.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="text-center col-md-6 text-md-left">
             <h4>Title</h4>
             <img class="img-fluid d-md-none" src="..." />
             <p>
                 Paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                 adipiscing elit
             </p>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">More</a>           
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block" src="... />
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

On mobile, the image on the right column is not showing due to `d-none`:

[image]

On desktop, the image on the right column is showing due to `d-md-block`, but the image between the Title and Paragraph is not showing due to `d-md-none`:

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/235510/